# Why is VSCode creating a history file?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

VSCode keeps creating a history file even after I delete it. If I don't delete it, it accumulates to over 5000+ pending changes in my source control tab, and I don't know what I did with my settings for it to keep recreating the history folder. How can I delete this for good? I don't know if it affects my other files, and based on my history of deleting it, I don't think it does.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be coming from mistakenly installing a VSCode extension called Local History by xyz. The description has it that "Every time you modify a file, a copy of the old contents is kept in the local history. At any time, you can compare a file with any older version from the history. It can help you out when you change or delete a file by accident. The history can also help you out when your workspace has a catastrophic problem. Each file revision is stored in a separate file inside the .history folder of your workspace directory (you can also configure another location, see local-history.path). e.g., .history/foo/bar/myFile_20151212205930.ts"
[Local History](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUpM3.png)

Simply search the extension on VSCode and uninstall it and your life would be patches of green.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can always add a `.gitignore` file and add  the following line in it. This way your git engine won't pick them up.

```
.vscode
```

It just means you have a lot of vscode settings in your local, you can ignore  them or delete them if you don't want to keep these editor settings. These settings won't affect any other files or other people's computer, as long as they don't get committed into the code repository.

Comment: I'll try this. Thanks!